# Excel get the difference in date by month for a sorted group of ids

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset

Using the example below I can sort the list by Id to group them but i am having a hard time writing a formula that will give me the difference in date by month for each group of Id

```
Date         ID
5/13/2022   IC12
3/18/2022   IC12    
9/17/2021   IC13    
7/16/2021   IC13
```

formulas I have tried

```
DATEDIF(MAXIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,"IC12"),MINIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,"IC12"),"m"))
```

but it does not seem to be work

now for me to get the first group of Id correct i used the formula

```
=(TODAY()-(IF([@[ID]]="IC12",MIN(A2:A3))))/(365/12)
```

which gives me what I want but I cannot use it for the rest of the data set which is almost 100k lines due to having different group of Id

```
5/13/2022   IC12    10.03
3/18/2022   IC12    10.03
```

Comment: Are you sure that `[Advisory ID]` is correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MINIFS` to check against the ID of the current row:

```
=(TODAY()-MINIFS([Date],[ID],[@ID]))/(365/12)
```

UPDATE according to comments:

```
=(MAXIFS([Date],[ID],[@ID]) - MINIFS([Date],[ID],[@ID]))/(365/12)
```

Comment: is there a way to calculate the min and max difference in months instead of the todays date - min

Comment: Can you give an example - I am not sure if I understand

Comment: I was trying to use the DATEDIF(max-min, "m") formula to give me the difference in date between two dates like these two 
Date            ID         months
5/18/2022   IC12          2
3/18/2022   IC12          2

Comment: this Gave me #NUM error... =DATEDIF(MAXIFS([Date],[ID],[@[ID]]),MINIFS([Date ],[ID],[@[ID]]),"m")

Comment: So you want the diff between the min and the max date of an ID?

Comment: I think I Got it Its because MAX- MIN is wrong its MIN - MAX